# What is the point of DbContext proxy objects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I'm trying to learn more about Entity Framework 5 and the `DbContext`, and I have a question about entity proxies.

Given a generated `Alert` entity class:

```
public partial class Alert
{
    public Alert()
    {
        this.Readings = new HashSet<Reading>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reading> Readings { get; set; }
}
```

The following unit test code passes:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var alert = context.Alerts.Create();

    // Entity is a proxy
    Assert.AreNotSame(entity.GetType(), ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType()));

    // Related entity collections are just HashSet<T>
    Assert.AreSame(typeof(HashSet<Reading>), alert.Readings.GetType());

    // Attach entity to the context
    context.Alerts.Attach(alert);

    var entry = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<Alert>().Single();

    // Initially it's unchanged
    Assert.AreEqual(EntityState.Unchanged, entry.State);

    // Change a property
    alert.Title = "Changed title";

    // However it's still unchanged
    Assert.AreEqual(EntityState.Unchanged, entry.State);
}
```

I've looked around online to try and find a definitive explanation of what generated proxy objects actually do. Some questions I have:

- As far as I can tell, the association property getter/setter is overridden. What logic is added here? Is anything else done in the proxy?
- The debugger shows a field called `_entityWrapper` of type `System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships<System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Alert_BF4E356370B8B5053A3384B5FAD30ECBA505359B71D47EBD90A674A9404D517C>`. What is this for?
- Will making attribute properties virtual do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an [answer by Rowan Miller in this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99d8d4a1-5ab1-42dc-b9db-5087be02162d/code-first-ef4-with-ntier-im-really-stuck-on-this-one-issue) (emphasis mine):

> **If you make all your properties virtual** then EF will generate proxy classes at runtime that derives from your POCO classed, these proxies allow EF to find out about changes in real time rather than having to capture the original values of your object and then scan for changes when you save (this is obviously has performance and memory usage benefits but the difference will be negligible unless you have a large number of entities loaded into memory). These are known as 'change tracking proxies'. **If you [only] make your navigation properties virtual** then a proxy is still generated but it is much simpler and just includes some logic to perform lazy loading when you access a navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

EF uses proxy objects to track changes dynamically  and to use lazy loading. When we have defined a property as virtual EF can override it to support these behaviors.

1. We need lazy loading to load navigation properties whenever we access it
2. Dynamic change tracking , If we do some change on a property the proxy will notify that to the change tracker immediately. If we do not use dynamic change tracking  change tracker needs to go through all the properties before save changes , to discover changes.

So try doing this,

```
alert.Title = "Changed title";
context.DetectChanges();
```

Comment: Lazy loading through the relations seems legit. However the dynamic change tracking doesn't work for properties as far as I can tell. The code you show is the same for both proxy and non-proxy situations.

Comment: You need to define all the properties as virtual just like the navigation properties .

Comment: Defining the `Title` property in my example as `virtual` has no effect on the outcome of the test case I demonstrated. The entity is still `Unchanged` after changing `Title`.